# How to "add parsed string that used filter" to an String ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, regex, list

Right now I have collection of substrings that match the pattern. I want to add these filtered substrings to an arraylist.

Right now have this:

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*");
   
String result = reg.splitAsStream("A*B*C*D*E*F*G*A*B*C*D*E*F*A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H")
        .filter(role -> role.matches("A"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

System.out.println(result);
```

I want to add the printed out result which is all the A into a arraylist I need help with adding it to arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your application prints out the following.

`A,A,A`

If you are saying that you want the result to be placed into an `ArrayList`, then all you have to do is use the [`ArrayList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) constructor that accepts a `Collection`, then simply turn your `Stream` into a `Collection`. Like this.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SOQ_20220516_1
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*");
   
      var result = new ArrayList<>(reg.splitAsStream("A*B*C*D*E*F*G*A*B*C*D*E*F*A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H")
         .filter(role -> role.matches("A"))
         .map(String::trim)
         .toList());
   
      System.out.println(result);
   
   }

}
```

Of course, if you are willing to use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead of an `ArrayList`, then this becomes much simpler. Like this.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SOQ_20220516_1
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*");
   
      var result = reg.splitAsStream("A*B*C*D*E*F*G*A*B*C*D*E*F*A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H")
         .filter(role -> role.matches("A"))
         .map(String::trim)
         .toList();
   
      System.out.println(result);
   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add every matched result specifically into an `ArrayList`, then you could use the terminal operation `collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` and provide the `ArrayList` constructor as the factory method for the `toCollection`. This will specifically instantiate an `ArrayList` containing all your matched results.

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*");
ArrayList<String> listRes = reg.splitAsStream("A*B*C*D*E*F*G*A*B*C*D*E*F*A*B*C*D*E*F*G*H")
        .filter(role -> role.matches("A"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

##### EDIT

In case you also want to include the results that start with `A`, then you could use the following regex within the `filter` aggregate operation: `A.*`. The code will look like this:

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*");
ArrayList<String> listRes = reg.splitAsStream("A123*B*C*D*E*F*G*A222*A*B*C*A")
        .filter(role -> role.matches("A.*"))
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thanks I have one more question lets says the first character in A was replaced with A123, second A was replaced with A222 but I want to filter out all characters that start with A would that be possible?

Comment: @Chenman what do you mean with filter out? include or exclude? for example, if this was the sample string `A123*B*C*D*E*F*G*A222*A*B*C*A` do you want as a result: `[A123, A222, A, A]` - `[A123, A222]` or `[A, A]`?

Comment: I would want the result to be [A123, A222, A, A]

Comment: Let say * replaced with |*| in the string so I change the Pattern.compile("|\\*|") that works but now the filter part doesn't work. Only filters A doesnt give the [A123,A222,A,A] result anymore, can u elaborate how the filter part would work?